# AutoHotKey temporarily rebind Winkey

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I've got a wireless keyboard that puts some media keys on top of the Function keys, so that by default F4 is actually lock (`Rwin & l`) and Fn+F4 is a real F4. So I'd like to basically switch those around. Here's what the key history shows:

```
VK  SC  Type    Up/Dn   Elapsed Key
-------------------------------------
73  03E         d       17.32   F4              ; Fn+F4
73  03E         u       0.16    F4              
5C  15C         d       2.96    Right Windows   ; F4
4C  026         d       0.00    L               
5C  15C         u       0.13    Right Windows   
4C  026         u       0.00    L
```

This doesn't do anything:

```
SC15C & SC026::MsgBox,Pressed F4
```

But this prints that I hit F4 then goes to the login screen:

```
Rwin & l::MsgBox,Pressed F4
```

So how can I stop it from switching to the login screen? Ideally I'd like F4 (which registers as `Rwin & l`) to just send F4, Fn+F4 to send `Rwin & l`, and also have them work with other keys (e.g., a manual `!F4` should still close a window). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, the keyboard was an *HP Wireless Mini Keyboard*. I could not find any software solution that was low level enough to modify/block `RWin & l` being sent (editing the Registry didn't help). After three calls to HP Support and an un-answered email, I took the keyboard back instead. I was told that a piece of software called *HP Quick Launch Buttons* could help, but I don't have an HP machine (just the keyboard) and none of the installers on the HP website worked for me.

To answer my original question: "it is not possible."

Answer (score 0):

Is there an F-Lock on the keyboard?

A lot of times the Fn key is handled internally and cannot be detected by AutoHotKey.

Comment: No, there isn't an F-Lock. I understand that point about Fn being possibly undetectable. If there is a way to temporarily disable the WinKey then I think I can get this to do exactly what I want...